# Order of radical dimerization ability

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, electrons, reactivity, radicals

In a question I came across recently, it was asked to arrange the following radicals in the ascending order of dimerization ability.

[image]

I have read about the triphenylmethyl radical undergoing Gomberg dimerization, but I couldn't relate it to this question. Please explain the order of dimerization.
Also, please suggest a valid source (books or journals) to read more about the same.

Comment: Hint: I which position the radicals bind?

Comment: They bind on the para position. So, does it mean that since the para position on B is hindered, it would be the least, in dimerization, and the order is A>C>B? Is there any other effect, or any other factor that has a role in dimerization, like radical stability?

Comment: Fluorine in p- has much bigger effect than just steric.

Comment: Could someone please explain the answer?